# How to restart consumer rabbitmq pika python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, twisted, pika

I am experiencing some dropouts on consumers I have setup using the pika library for rabbitmq.  Along with pika I am using the twisted implementation to setup async consumers.  I am not sure why this is happening but I wish to implement a reconnect if the consumer drops out and not sure how to go about doing this.  Here is my current implementation

```
class Consumer(object):
def __init__(self, queue, exchange, routingKey, medium, signalRcallbackFunc):
    self._queue_name = queue
    self.exchange = exchange
    self.routingKey = routingKey
    self.medium = medium
    print "client on"
    self.channel = None
    self.medium.client.on(signalRcallbackFunc, self.callback)

def on_connected(self, connection):
    d = connection.channel()
    d.addCallback(self.got_channel)
    d.addCallback(self.queue_declared)
    d.addCallback(self.queue_bound)
    d.addCallback(self.handle_deliveries)
    d.addErrback(log.err)

def got_channel(self, channel):
    self.channel = channel
    self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=500)
    return self.channel.queue_declare(queue=self._queue_name, durable=True)

def queue_declared(self, queue):
    self.channel.queue_bind(queue=self._queue_name,
                            exchange=self.exchange,
                            routing_key=self.routingKey)

def queue_bound(self, ignored):
    return self.channel.basic_consume(queue=self._queue_name)

def handle_deliveries(self, queue_and_consumer_tag):
    queue, consumer_tag = queue_and_consumer_tag
    self.looping_call = task.LoopingCall(self.consume_from_queue, queue)

    return self.looping_call.start(0)

def consume_from_queue(self, queue):
    d = queue.get()
    return d.addCallback(lambda result: self.handle_payload(*result))

def handle_payload(self, channel, method, properties, body):
    print(body)
    print(properties.headers)
    channel.basic_ack(method.delivery_tag)
    print "#####################################" + method.delivery_tag + "###################################"

def callback(self, data):
    #self.channel.basic_ack(data, multiple=True)
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

You could register an 'on-close' handler with the connection within the on_connected callback. This gets called when the connection is lost. Here, you can re-establish a new connection.

The following example is relatively useful and it's a strategy I have used to good effect...
http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/asynchronous_consumer_example.html

For the twisted pika library the `add_on_close_callback` method will probably get you quite far (although I have not tested). https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/modules/adapters/twisted.html

Comment: how would I go about doing this, using the twisted protocol

Comment: It seems the twisted implementation of the pika library has similar methods available to register listeners for the connection-closed event. You could try using the `add_on_close_callback` method. See [link]https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.0/modules/adapters/twisted.html

Comment: I have read this, but am not sure how to implement this in my solution

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't just close the connection and reopen it?

```
@contextmanager
def with_pika_connection():
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(worker_config.username, worker_config.password)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host=worker_config.host,
        credentials=credentials,
        port=worker_config.port,
    ))

    try:
        yield connection
    finally:
        connection.close()


@contextmanager
def with_pika_channel(queuename):
    with with_pika_connection() as connection:
        channel = connection.channel()


while True:
    while not stopping:
         try:
                with with_pika_channel(queuename) as (connection, channel):
                    consumer_tag = channel.basic_consume(
                        callback,
                        queue=queuename,
                    )
                    channel.start_consuming()
         except Exception as e:
              reportException(e) 
              # Continue
```